# Restarting Program Based on User Input

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I want to restart my game based on the user input.

For example, if i print "*Do you want to play again, type (5) for yes or (10) for no*". I've tried to add `do while` loops but I have no idea what to do. Any help with the code to restart the program would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sticks3 {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     int numSticks = 21;
     System.out.println("Would You Like to go first? (Yes/No)");
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String goFirst = input.nextLine();
     Scanner take = new Scanner (System.in);
     int numToTake = 0;
     int score = 0;





     while (numSticks > 0) {

       if (goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("yes")) {
         System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
         System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
         numToTake = take.nextInt();

         if (numToTake > 2) {
           numToTake = 2;

         }

         else if (numToTake < 1) {
           numToTake = 1;
         }
         numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

         if (numSticks <= 0) {
           System.out.println("You lose");
           System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
         }
         else {

           if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
             numToTake = 1;
           }
           else {
             numToTake = 2;
           }
           System.out.println("Computer takes " + numToTake + " sticks " );
           numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

           if (numSticks <= 0) {
             System.out.println(" You win ");
             score++;
             System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
           }
         }

      }
      else {
             if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
             numToTake = 1;
           }
           else {
             numToTake = 2;
           }
           System.out.println("Computer takes" + numToTake + " sticks " );
           numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

           if (numSticks <= 0) {
             System.out.println("You win");
             score++;
             System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
               System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
               numToTake = take.nextInt();

               if (numToTake > 2) {
                   numToTake = 2;
               }
               else if (numToTake < 1){
                   numToTake = 1;
               }
               numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

               if(numSticks <= 0){
                   System.out.println("You win");
                   score++;
                   System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
               }

           }

      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: **I've tried to add do while loops** really? because your current code is missing it

Comment: You can do a do-while loop, do {your main game code} while(user still wants to play). If they say yes, you can reset the game constructor/other variables. You can even include the set up at the start of the do while as you will need to set it up at least once, and then if they want to continue you just rerun it and thus reset it.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to put all of the code in main in a function. Then call that function in a loop. Like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        runGame(scanner);
        // Game has finished

        System.out.println("Do you want to play again, type (5) for yes or (10) for no");

        if (scanner.nextLine().equals("10")) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

The scanner is passed to the function as the same one can be used there. There's no reason to have multiple scanners in your program, [and it should be avoided](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream).

Comment: I dont really understand what your saying

Comment: No not yet, Im trying to keep it as basic as possible.

Comment: Ok. Your code simply goes instead of runGame(scanner).

Comment: ok, but at the end it just keeps repeating the line "System.out.println("Do you want to play again, type (5) for yes or (10) for no");" Thats not what I want

Comment: You need to put all of your code starting from int numsticks = 21 into what i posted, replacing runGame(scanner).

Comment: I did but it doesnt seem to work. Thanks for the help though! Really appreciate it

Comment: I'm almost positive that some bracket ended up being misplaced for you, causing some loop to be on the wrong level. Anyway, this should work: [http://pastebin.com/004Qz6sJ](http://pastebin.com/004Qz6sJ)

Answer (score 0):

Build a while (or do-while, which would be even a better choice) around it. Ask if it should be played again, if yes the condition of the while stays true, otherwise change it. Of course you have to initialize numSticks, numToTake and score to 0 again.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sticks3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int numSticks = 21;
        System.out.println("Would You Like to go first? (Yes/No)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String goFirst = input.nextLine();
        Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numToTake = 0;
        int score = 0;

        boolean playAgain = true;
        Scanner askPlayAgainScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (playAgain == true) {

            numSticks = 21;
            numToTake = 0;
            score = 0;

            while (numSticks > 0) {

                if (goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("yes")) {
                    System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
                    System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
                    numToTake = take.nextInt();

                    if (numToTake > 2) {
                        numToTake = 2;

                    }

                    else if (numToTake < 1) {
                        numToTake = 1;
                    }
                    numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                    if (numSticks <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("You lose");
                        System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
                    } else {

                        if ((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
                            numToTake = 1;
                        } else {
                            numToTake = 2;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Computer takes " + numToTake + " sticks ");
                        numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                        if (numSticks <= 0) {
                            System.out.println(" You win ");
                            score++;
                            System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    if ((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
                        numToTake = 1;
                    } else {
                        numToTake = 2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Computer takes" + numToTake + " sticks ");
                    numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                    if (numSticks <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("You win");
                        score++;
                        System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
                        System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
                        numToTake = take.nextInt();

                        if (numToTake > 2) {
                            numToTake = 2;
                        } else if (numToTake < 1) {
                            numToTake = 1;
                        }
                        numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                        if (numSticks <= 0) {
                            System.out.println("You win");
                            score++;
                            System.out.println("Your score is " + score);

                        }



                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? true for yes, false for no: ");
            boolean askPlayAgain = askPlayAgainScanner.nextBoolean();
        }
    }
}
```